# Django-rest progress bar upload

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have django model with  `FileField` and related django-rest serializer. I need to implement progress bar upload. There is [default solution](https://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/678/) for django, but how to perform it in terms of DRF?

UPD: The problem is about requests and views. How to make `APIView`  with `parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser,)` and `post` method work  with `request.META['X-Progress-ID']`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should integrate the progress bar using javascript. There are many js plugins to create progress bars out there. For instance you could use [jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload). A minimal example could look like this ([see docs](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin)):

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    /* ... */
    progressall: function (e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        $('#progress .bar').css(
            'width',
            progress + '%'
        );
    }
});

<div id="progress">
    <div class="bar" style="width: 0%;"></div>
</div>
```