# How do I receive file upload progress using Django/DRF

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I'm not sure if there is an answer for this out there so here goes...
I am building an rest API project using django and django restframework where consumers have the ability to upload files. I can't seem to find any docs or examples of how to report file upload progress to the requesting client. How do I go about this?

Comment: Most solutions report the upload progress purely client side. `XMLHttpRequest`s raise a [`progress` event](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#events) with the status of the data transfer.

Answer (score 0):

You should integrate the progress bar using javascript. There are many js plugins to create progress bars out there.
[Django-rest progress bar upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36147098/django-rest-progress-bar-upload)

Answer (score 0):

Django also provide progress bar for file upload progress.
[Django file upload progress docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/file-uploads/#id1)